# I need help getting Javascript to read an HTML form, and assign it to a specific array

Tags: javascript

I need help getting javascript to read an html input form, and assign the input to an array, or atleast what i think is an array....im not sure.

i want to take the data from an html form, and put it in here:

```
var users = ['"This is a random qoute"-lastname,firstname."','"This is a random
qoute"-lastname,firstname."'];
```

is this possible?

Comment: using jquery you can do this very easily..are you okay with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array of the text input names and values, the following will do the job. If you want to

serialize a form for posting, that takes a little more code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInputs(form) {
  var input, inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var result = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    input = inputs[i];

    if (input.type == 'text') {
      result.push(input.name + ': ' + input.value)
    }
  }
  return result;
}

</script>

<form>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>name<td><input type="text" name="userName">
  <tr>
   <td>age<td><input type="text" name="userAge">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Show inputs" 
       onclick="alert(getInputs(this.form));">
</table>
</form>
```

Shows `"userName: <value>, userAge: <value>"`

Answer (score 0):

Check about [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)
**Example:**

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var params = $(this).serializeArray();
  console.log(params);
    return false;
});
```

**The console will show something like:**

```
[
    {
        name: "input1Name",
        value: "input1Value"
    },

    {
        name: "input2Name",
        value: "input2Value"
    }
]
```

After your form submit you can access your params in objects, like:

**Get all**

```
jQuery.each(params, function(objPosition, obj){
    alert("name: " + obj.name + " Value: " + obj.value);
});
```

**OR** to **get one** ( in this case's the first one)

```
alert("name: " + params[0].name + " Value: " + params[0].value);
```

You can see it **working here**: http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Jfu9H/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely with [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

If you are not familiar with jQuery use this [Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp) to understand its basics. It's a Java Script Library.

Now you can work according to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jCXV2/) written by me.

it reads form element values into a string,

```
var srt=$("form").serialize();
```

and split the resulted string from '&' sing to get the expected string array.

```
var srtArray=srt.split('&');
```

result is something like this,

```
["text1=Lasantha", "dropDownList1=Single", "List1=Multiple1", "List1=Multiple3", "checkBox2=check2", "radioButton1=radio1"]
```

it is in the form of,

```
["name=value","name=value"....]
```